# Split a 2D list into square blocks with equally distributed elements

Tags: python, arrays, list, split

Let's say I have a list

```
ls = [[1,2,3], 
      [4,5,6], 
      [7,8,9]]
```

Now I want to split this list into other smaller square 2d lists where the square's side is determined by an input k. So if k was 2, I would get 4 new lists trying to distribute the elements equally between them and those lists would be:

```
L1 = [1,2,
      4,5]

L2 = [3,
      6]

L3 = [7,8]

L4 = [9]
```

I am not so sure how can I do this. I can split a list if I decide the number of squares, but not if the number of squares is a random number input from the user. I tried this, but I am not sure how do I continue from this point, after deciding the first block of elements.

```
ls = [[1,2,3], 
      [4,5,6], 
      [7,8,9]]

def splitList(ls, k):
  if len(ls) == 1:
    return ls[0]
  else:
    for x in range(k):
      for y in range(k):
        print (ls[x][y])


print (splitList(ls, 2))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Arrays and lists are not interchangeable terms in Python. If your don't know the difference, you're using lists. Also, your lists are not "equally distributed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this is to use [numpy arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) instead of "2d lists" (you can easily convert one to another) and do [basic slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
import numpy as np

ls = np.array([[1,2,3], 
               [4,5,6], 
               [7,8,9]])

nr = ls.shape[0]  # number of rows
nc = ls.shape[1]  # number of columns
```

Then do the slicing

```
L1 = ls[:k, :k]
L2 = ls[:k, k:nc]
L3 = ls[k:nr, :k]
L4 = ls[k:nr, k:nc]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ***have*** to split a 2D *list of lists*, you should not use a Numpy `np.array`, that is not a list...

Let's define an alternate way of printing a list of lists

```
In [79]: def pmat(mat):
    ...:     for row in mat:
    ...:         print(''.join('%5d'%x for x in row))
```

The numerical parameters

```
In [80]: nr, nc, k = 6, 8, 4
```

Generate a LoL and check it by printing

```
In [81]: a = [[1+c+r*nc for c in range(nc)] for r in range(nr)]
In [82]: pmat(a)
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24
   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32
   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40
   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48
```

We have no smart indexing, so we have to use regular indexing (i.e., double couple of brackets) and a list comprehension

```
In [83]: a11 = [a[r][:k] for r in range(k)]    ; a12 = [a[r][k:] for r in range(k)]
In [84]: a21 = [a[r][:k] for r in range(k,nr)] ; a22 = [a[r][k:] for r in range(k,nr)]
```

Finally we check our results.

```
In [85]: pmat(a11)
    1    2    3    4
    9   10   11   12
   17   18   19   20
   25   26   27   28

In [86]: pmat(a12)
    5    6    7    8
   13   14   15   16
   21   22   23   24
   29   30   31   32

In [87]: pmat(a21)
   33   34   35   36
   41   42   43   44

In [88]: pmat(a22)
   37   38   39   40
   45   46   47   48
```